# can't download a file with python but i can from the browser

Tags: python, url, download, urllib2

I am trying to make a function that will download file from the internet. If I go to the direct web address I do get the images or download the files. But, when I am running my code, it just hangs and then I get the timeout error. Is there any particular reason why that might be happening?

```
#fpp = "http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/wxDbViewer.zip"
fpp = "http://www.gunnerkrigg.com//comics/00000001.jpg"
download_file(fpp)
```

This is my function:

```
import urllib2

def download_file(url_path):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_path)
    data = response.read()
```

Is there any particular reason why might work from the browser but not in the code?

this is the error i get:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/dk/testing/myfile.py", line 42, in <module>
    download_file(fpp)
  File "/Users/dk/Documents/testing/code_project.py", line 154, in download_file
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>
```

Comment: maybe irrelevant but why double slashes here: `..igg.com//comics...`

Comment: Your function arguments don't match the ones that you are passing to it. Something is missing ?

Comment: This is quite flawed, almost nothing fits together. Your function has no `kwargs`, but you pass one; your function has a `self` argument, which seems as if you have copied it from a class; your function does not save a single bit.

Comment: sorry was part of a class and i just took it out so it be easier to read in the forum. =(   i try with the comic and the zip file but still timesout.

Comment: The bits and pieces you have posted do not add up to a valid program. Please create a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem you are having.  (In your case, it might be only 5-10 lines long). Please [edit] your question and copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See [mcve] for more info.